# How To Show Time In Hours If The Minutes Are Greater Than 60?

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, time

Hi Friends nd developers, how are you? I need some help. i am using johncms v6.2 . i want to show post time in hours if they cross 60 minutes. here is my code.

```
    public static function display_date($var)
    {
        $shift = (self::$system_set['timeshift'] + self::$user_set['timeshift']) * 3600;
        if (date("N", $var + $shift) == 1) {
            $thu_time = 'Monday';
        }else if (date("N", $var + $shift) == 2) {
            $thu_time = 'Tuseday';
        }else if (date("N", $var + $shift) == 3) {
            $thu_time = 'Wednesday';
        }else if (date("N", $var + $shift) == 4) {
            $thu_time = 'Thursday';
        }else if (date("N", $var + $shift) == 5) {
            $thu_time = 'Friday';
        }else if (date("N", $var + $shift) == 6) {
            $thu_time = 'Saturday';
        }else if (date("N", $var + $shift) == 7) {
            $thu_time = 'Sunday';
        }
        if (date('Y', $var) == date('Y', time())) {
            $jun = round((time()-$var)/60);
            if ($jun < 1) {
                return 'Just Now';
            }else if($jun >= 1 && $jun < 60){
                return $jun . ' Minutes Ago';
            }else if($jun >= 60 && $jun > 60){
            return $jun . ' Minutes Ago';
            }else{
                if (date('z', $var + $shift) == date('z', time() + $shift)) {
                    return self::$lng['today'] . ' at ' . date("H:i", $var + $shift);
                }else if (date('z', $var + $shift) == date('z', time() + $shift) - 1) {
                    return self::$lng['yestday'] . '  ' . date("H", $var + $shift).' Hours Ago ';
                }else if (date('z', $var + $shift) == date('z', time() + $shift) - 2) {
                    return $thu_time . ' at ' . date("H:i", $var + $shift);
                }else if (date('z', $var + $shift) == date('z', time() + $shift) - 3) {
                    return $thu_time . ' at ' . date("H:i", $var + $shift);
                }else{
                    return date("j", $var + $shift) . ' / ' . date("n", $var + $shift) . ' at ' . date("H:i", $var + $shift);
                }
            }
        }

        return $thu_time . ', '.date("j", $var + $shift) . ' / ' . date("n", $var + $shift) . ' ' . date("Y", $var + $shift);
    }
```

here you can see in the photo its showing 735 minutes i want to show this in hours. please anyone help me.!
[ here is screenshot] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/l26Fs.jpg)

Comment: `elseif` is one word in php.  See PSR-12 coding standards.  Please remove the irrelevant greeting and "please help".

Comment: i can't understand what have you explained me sir, :)

Comment: this seems like javascript, not java

Comment: A datetime object with diff() is the ONLY way that I do this in professional code.